# Changing DIV color dynamically on mouseover

Tags: javascript, dom, styles, onmouseover

I want to change the div background color to green onmouseover event but I'm not sure why I keep getting this error  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

Here's my JS code:

// JavaScript Document

```
s1= new String()
var myArray = new Array();
var div_id=0;

myArray[0] = "Donald Duck";
myArray[1] = "Winnie Pooh";
myArray[2] = "Komal Waseem";
myArray[3] = "Hockey";
myArray[4] = "Basketball";
myArray[5] = "Shooting";
myArray[6] = "Mickey Mouse";


function test(){
s1 = document.getElementById('filter').value;
var myRegex = new RegExp((s1),"ig");
arraysearch(myRegex);
}



function arraysearch(myRegex){ 
var flag=0;

for(b=1; b<=div_id; b++)
    {
   var d = document.getElementById('lc');
   var olddiv= document.getElementById("div" + b);
   if(olddiv){
   d.removeChild(olddiv);}
   }

for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{ 
if (myArray[i].match(myRegex)){ 
      div_id++;
      flag=1;
      document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='visible';
      var element = document.createElement("div");
      element.setAttribute('id', "div" + div_id);
      element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[i]));
      document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);

      var x =document.getElementsByTagName("div")
      for(t=0; t<x.length; t++)
      {
      //alert(t);
      if(x[t]){
      x[t].onmouseover = function(){
      x[t].style.backgroundColor='green';
       }
       }
}
}
    if (flag ==0){
    document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='hidden'; }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either change your JavaScript, this should work:

```
x[t].onmouseover = function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor='green';
}
```

The reason your original JavaScript doesn't work is because `t` has changed by the time you mouse-over, so `x[t]` inside the event handler cannot work.

Or you could use CSS:

```
div.myDiv:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Now I don't get the error but all of the divs are turning green when I hover on only one div!

Comment: Actually my container div 'lc' is also turning green so I have to figure out to exclude that from the mouseover event.

Answer (score 2):

In case, if you want the `div` to be green onhover, e.g: div id is mydiv, you could simply do something like this in your css.

```
 #mydiv{
     background-color:red;
}

#mydiv:hover{
    background-color:green;
}
```